# Can I edit XYZ simultaneously in pose mode?

Tags: interface

With most objects, I can drag my cursor through the XYZ properties, enter a value, and hit return to confirm. This changes all 3 values at once, like so:

[image: process working in object mode]

For some reason this process doesn't work in pose mode. It even shows all the properties changing in preview, but only one changes after hitting return. Here's the same process in pose mode:

[image: process not working in pose mode]

Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way to input values across multiple channels simultaneously?

Comment: Hi, I can't recreate this problem. Are you perhaps using some constraints on your bone?

Comment: Well I tried making a new armature in the same scene and it does not have this problem. But if I duplicate the problematic armature, the duplicate still has this problem. Actually it even does this when I enter values for the whole armature in object mode. So it seems to be something I've done to this specific armature. The bones I'm moving have no constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever was going wrong has since solved itself. Maybe something was fixed when I updated to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to directly fix this problem, but there is a way you can move around this problem and still do it faster.  In Blender you are able to maneuver to the next field by pressing tab.  This does not solve the problem, but it is faster than having to switch over to your mouse and clicking the next field.
Hope that is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad to help :D